# Regex matching a string without whitespace and hash # character

Tags: regex

I need to validate a text box to avoid the user to enter white space or hash tag #. As of now i tried below regular expressions and achieved only to restrict space.

**Case 1: Regular expression restricting Space :**  `^\S+$` -  This is working

**Case 2: Regular expression to restrict Space and # hash tag** - `(\S+$)[!#]`  This is not working

I need to restrict the user entering white space and hash tag #.

Answer (score 4):

You need to unroll the `\S` as `[^\s]` and add the `#` to it:

```
^[^\s#]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ4rY7/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[^\s#]+` - 1 or more  (`+`) characters other than (see `[^...]`, a *negated character class*) whitespace (`\s`) and `#` symbol
- `$`  - end of string.